# paddle payment webhook data error in nestjs

Tags: nestjs, sandbox

I am writing the `payment code` in the `sandbox` of `paddle` using nestjs and html.

I made two products, a regular `product` and a `plan`.

If I paid for the `plan`, I could receive `checkout_id` information from the webhook.

However, when purchasing a general product, the following information was obtained through the webhook.

```js
{
  event_time: '2022-08-22 08:54:19',
  p_country: 'CN',
  p_coupon: '',
  p_coupon_savings: '0.00',
  p_currency: 'CNY',
  p_custom_data: '',
  p_earnings: '{"7668":"3.2000"}',
  p_order_id: '407118',
  p_paddle_fee: '3.77',
  p_price: '6.97',
  p_product_id: '33625',
  p_quantity: '1',
  p_sale_gross: '6.97',
  p_tax_amount: '0.00',
  p_used_price_override: '0',
  passthrough: '{"userId":9}',
  quantity: '1',
  p_signature: 'bZhkDR+M/G...HIU+D8ZaQ9BKMGL2a/K63eoAdkU='
}
```

And on the order page, I selected the quantity as 3, the quantity is 1 and the webhook is called 3 times...

```js
//sandbox
            Paddle.Environment.set('sandbox');
            Paddle.Setup({ 
                vendor: xxxx,

                eventCallback: function (data) {
                        // The data.event will specify the event type
                        if (data.event === 'Checkout.Loaded') {
                          console.log(data.eventData) // Data specifics on the event
                        } else if (data.event === 'Checkout.Complete') {
                          console.log(data.eventData) // Data specifics on the event
                        } else if (data.event === 'Checkout.Close') {
                          console.log(data.eventData) // Data specifics on the event
                        }
                      }
 });
            Paddle.Checkout.open({ 
                product: xxxxx
                , allowQuantity:true
                , passthrough:{
                    userId:9
                } 
            });
```

Above is my html code. The eventCallback function is not called on that page.

Is it a `sandbox` issue? Please let me know how I can solve the above problems!

---

[summary]

1. I want to get `checkout_id` through webhook in general product payment.
2. If I select quantity `3` when paying for a product, the quantity is displayed as `1` in the webhook and the webhook is called `3 times`.
3. The `eventCallback` function is not called in the `html`.

Comment: same problem with Next.js

Comment: Having same issue with React-Native. @user10874312 any update on this?